# Permissions to get facebook page ID via API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to get a Page ID from a page URL (ex: Facebook.com/Nike).

Facebook API returns a message saying I need a permission (Page Public Metadata or Page Public Content access) that is only available to apps with a Verified Business. Is this accurate? Is there no way to get Page ID from URL without an app that has a verified biz?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is accurate. Without either of those, you can not get any data about a page you don't have admin access to, any more. (Which kinda begs the question what you would need these IDs for then to begin with?)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can and without permission but it may fail when you deploy your app but give it a try

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch') // use 1.7.3 version
const getPageId = async (pageUrl) => {
    const res = await fetch(pageUrl)
    const html = await res.text()
    try {
        const id = JSON.parse("{" + html.match(/"pageID":"[\d+]*"/g)[0] + "}").pageID
        console.log(id);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('something went wrong');
    }
}
getPageId('https://facebook.com/Nike') // id => 15087023444
```

good luck